# Does Spring parent bean received from factory has properties?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have an abstract parent bean that has map property.
This map must be merged with map property of child.
It is work. But when I put this bean as inner in factory - map property seems disappears.
I suppose that fields of inner bean are unavailable for child.

```
<bean id="parent" factory-bean="factory"
 factory-method="createbean"> 
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean abstract="true">
       <property name="prop" > 
         <map>
           <entry ............
           .................
         </map 
 ...............
```

Next bean:

```
  <bean id="child" parent="parent">
```

Is it correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
<bean id="parent" abstract="true" factory-bean="factory" factory-method="createBean">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <props>
            <prop key="One">one-value</prop>
            <prop key="Three">three-value</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="child" parent="parent">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <props merge="true">
            <prop key="Two">two-value</prop>
            <prop key="Three">not-three-value</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

When the child bean is returned the Properties object passed in the will have the values:

```
One=one-value
Two=two-value
Three=not-three-value
```

Note that the value of the "Three" key was overridden because it was included in the child bean